# ejabberd component port

Tags: components, xmpp, ejabberd

may i know if i want to use component to connect to ejabberd, do i connect to port 5222 or do i need to create new port? any guide on how to create it?

Answer (score 9):

Each component has to use a different port. You can set that up in the ejabberd config.

The setup happens with the `listen` block. For example :

```
{5237, ejabberd_service, [{hosts, ["gg.example.org"],
                             [{password, "ggsecret"}]}]},
```

Good luck!

Comment: let say my domain is jabber.net  , i need to put subdomain.jabber.net as host?

Comment: Yes, you do need to put subdomain.jabber.net. Make sure that your component uses this to connect.